# count characters occurences in string

Tags: python

I want to find out how often does "reindeer" (in any order) come in a random string  and what is the left over string after "reindeer" is removed.  I need to preserve order of the left over string

So for example

`"erindAeer" -> A` (reindeer comes 1 time)

```
"ierndeBeCrerindAeer" -> ( 2 reindeers, left over is BCA)
```

I thought of sorting and  removing "reindeer", but i need to preserve the order . What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Do u want to check if the permutations of the string is in the target string?

Comment: You mean you want to replace the letters r,e,i,n,d,e,e,r,s equal number of times. After replacing the the leftover will have same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace those letters after knowing how many times they repeat, and `Counter` is convenient for counting elements.

```
from collections import Counter

def leftover(letter_set, string):
    lcount, scount = Counter(letter_set), Counter(string)
    repeat = min(scount[l] // lcount[l] for l in lcount)
    for l in lcount:
        string = string.replace(l, "", lcount[l] * repeat)
    return f"{repeat} {letter_set}, left over is {string}"

print(leftover("reindeer", "ierndeBeCrerindAeer"))
print(leftover("reindeer", "ierndeBeCrerindAeere"))
print(leftover("reindeer", "ierndeBeCrerindAee"))
```

Output:

```
2 reindeer, left over is BCA
2 reindeer, left over is BCAe
1 reindeer, left over is BCerindAee
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in Python:

```
def find_reindeers(s):
    rmap = {}
    for x in "reindeer":
        if x not in rmap:
            rmap[x] = 0
        rmap[x] += 1

    hmap = {key: 0 for key in "reindeer"}
    for x in s:
        if x in "reindeer":
            hmap[x] += 1

    total_occ = min([hmap[x]//rmap[x] for x in "reindeer"])

    left_over = ""
    print(hmap, rmap)
    for x in s:
        if (x in "reindeer" and hmap[x] > total_occ * rmap[x]) or (x not in "reindeer"):
            left_over += x

    return total_occ, left_over

print(find_reindeers("ierndeBeCrerindAeer"))
```

Output for `ierndeBeCrerindAeer`:

```
(2, "BCA")
```

Comment: There's a problem with `if (x in "reindeer" and hmap[x] > total_occ * rmap[x])`, if the letter in string appears more than the multiple of "reindeer", all that letter will be printed out. Use `"ierndeBeCrerindAeere"` (One more "e" at the end) as example, the result will be `(2, 'eeBeCeAeee')`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather simple approach using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def purge(pattern, string):
    scount, pcount = Counter(string), Counter(pattern)
    cnt = min(scount[x] // pcount[x] for x in pcount)
    scount.subtract(pattern * cnt)
    return cnt, "".join(scount.subtract(c) or c for c in string if scount[c])

>>> purge("reindeer", "ierndeBeCrerindAeer")
(2, 'BCA')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by using count and replace string function:

```py
import queue
word = "reindeer" 
given_string = "ierndeBeCrerindAeer"
new_string = ""
counter = 0
tmp = ""
letters = queue.Queue()



for i in given_string:
    if not i in word:
        new_string += i
    else:
        letters.put(i)


x = 0
while x < len(word):
    while not letters.empty():
        j = letters.get()
        if j == word[x]:
            tmp += j
            # print(tmp)
            break
        else:
            letters.put(j)
    x = x +1
    if tmp == word:
        counter += 1
        tmp = ""
        x = 0
print(f"The word {word} occurs {counter} times in the string {given_string}.")
print("The left over word is",new_string)
```

Output will be:

```py
The word reindeer occurs 2 times in the string ierndeBeCrerindAeer.
The left over word is BCA
```

It's easy to use queue here so that we don't repeat the elements that are already present or found.
Hope this answers your question, Thank you!

Comment: Replace "reindeers" in the string wont help with anything